# Interpret a byte array literal as hexadecimal byte array literal

Tags: python, json, character-encoding, cbor

Given the literal `b'a16568656C6c6f65776f726c64'` I would like it to be read such as the first digit is '0xa1', second is '0x65', etc...

This is a cbor encoding of `{"hello": "world"}` but the following program doesn't produce the expected output :

```
import cbor2
cipher=b'a16568656C6c6f65776f726c64'
plain=cbor2.loads(cipher)
print(plain)
```

print 1.
Right now it decodes as if 'a' is the first character of the literal.

Comment: Why not initialise `cipher` as a string instead of a `bytes` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the helper I was looking for :  `binascii.a2b_hex`

```
import cbor2
import binascii
cipher=b'a16568656C6c6f65776f726c64'
plain=cbor2.loads(binascii.a2b_hex(cipher))
print(plain)
```